# Simple SocketHandler for java8 logging(java.util.logging) throws ConnectionException

Tags: java, java.util.logging

The intention is to stream the log during runtime on a specific host:port, so that the logs are accessible to users outside the running system, from browser.

As you can see, i have created a simple SocketHandler for java8 logging(java.util.logging), is there something that i have missed?

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SocketHandler;
import java.util.logging.XMLFormatter;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("concrete.log");

        SocketHandler handler = new SocketHandler("HOSTNAME", 19004);

        LogRecord logRec = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Log recorded");

        handler.publish(logRec);

        handler.setFormatter(new XMLFormatter());

        logger.addHandler(handler);

        logger.info("socket handler info message");
    }
}
```

When i run the code, i see the following exception, i have tried checking the system firewall settings on both local(mac/windows) and remote(Linux) and seen that the settings do not block 19004 port

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
        at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.connect(SocketHandler.java:167)
        at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.<init>(SocketHandler.java:154)
        at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

UPDATE

As suggested by bosowski

When i create Socket to listen to a specific port, the log messages are getting printed on the console of the host. However, am unable to access hostname:port for the log to be streamed from the browser. Is there anything specific that needs to be performed after this step?
Please let me know

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try {

            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(19004);
            Socket soc = ss.accept();
            DataInputStream dis
                    = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());

            String str = (String)dis.readUTF();

            System.out.println("message= " + str);

            ss.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SocketHandler` does not open up a port to connect to, if that's what you're assuming. It tries to connect to the specified host and port, so you need to have a port that is listening on the host that you are trying to connect to.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SocketHandler.html#SocketHandler-java.lang.String-int-

> <handler-name>.host specifies the target host name to connect to (no default).

> <handler-name>.port specifies the target TCP port to use (no default).

If you do indeed have a listening TCP port on the hostname that you're trying to connect to, you can try running `sudo nmap -F hostname` to check if the port is indeed accessible from your machine.

Comment: Thank you. I have created a simple MyServer Socker class that listens to 19004 and the above suggested input works.

However, the log messages are not seen when i access "hostname":port

Comment: What do you mean by "the log messages are not seen when I access `hostname`:`port`"? Access in what way? The socket that you have opened is printing one message to console when it receives packets and then closing, terminating the server. For you to be able to see the logs in a browser in the way you are showing you will have to serve a web page.

Comment: I have setup a standalone tomcat server on 8080, when i use the streamhandler on 8080 port, the logs get displayed on the console. However, am unable continue to see the logs on tomcat 8080 port. 

As mentioned in the question above, the intention is to "stream logs", using StreamHandler onto a browser. is there a way i can do that using StreamHandler?
Please let me know.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stream logs onto a browser". You cannot stream logs directly onto a browser if that's what you mean. If you want to see logs displayed in a browser then you will have to set up a web server that will listen for the logs or obtain them in some way, save them somewhere (either in memory or on disk) and then serve them as HTTP content.

Comment: can you please tell me "what is the right way to make use of SocketHandler" in the context of logging?
is there any article that i can follow? (on the internet , there are no such articles that mention the usage of SocketHandler)